# Sending notifications to specific device using PHP?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying send notifications to specific device using PHP. I created the project in google console and start GCM service. I can send notifications to all devices but I want send to specific device for example: 26093d6bbddgggg, 26093d6bbddzzzz

How can i do it ?

I'm trying this PHP script

```
<?php
define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "AIzaSyCJiVkatisdQ44rEM353PFGbia29mBVscA");
define("GOOGLE_GCM_URL", "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

function send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $message) {

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => array( $reg_id ),
        'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Problem occurred: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
 }

$reg_id = "APA91bHuSGES.....nn5pWrrSz0dV63pg";
$msg = "Google Cloud Messaging working well";

send_gcm_notify($reg_id, $msg);
```

Comment: Gcm does not support sending notifications to all devices at once .  GCM supports sending a message to a specific device, or to all devices registered to same user ( are u testing with devices registered to same user ? )

Comment: @SojanVJose yep, send to all works fine but send to specific device doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about PHP. but when you are getting device Ids at that search device Id for specific device and then send.

Comment: you say get device id: `26093d6bbddgggg` and send ?

Comment: I think you are getting device Id here  $fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => array( $reg_id ),
        'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
    ); add loop and take which device Id you want and send on that device ID

Comment: then what is your problem?

Comment: can't send to specific device. for example, I have  `26093d6bbddgggg` does receive the notification, but `26093d6bbddzzzz` doesn't

Comment: then add your condition that on which device you want to send notification.

Comment: Ok just add 26093d6bbddgggg and 26093d6bbddzzzz these Ids in to list. and add for(int i = 0; i < list.size; i++). And in that for put your send GCM notification code. I am sure this will be work for you.

Comment: this is your code that you are adding in that for loop. $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, GOOGLE_GCM_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);  check and reply